# How to insert value in getViewType in android?

Tags: android

I am working on listview and I have an adapter in which I want to show two views. For this I'm using `listview` with custom base adapter. My code is working fine but I don't know what value I have to insert in `getViewType()`.

code:

```
private Context mContext;
private List<NewsSnippet> mItems;
private String TAG = CNewsAdpter.class.getSimpleName();

public CNewsAdpter(Context m_Context, List<NewsSnippet> items) {
    this.mContext = m_Context;
    mItems = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {// get total arraylist size
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {// get item position in array list
    return mItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "InflateParams"})
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (v == null) {
        // Inflate the layout according to the view type
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (type == 0) {
            // Inflate the layout with image
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_for_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vcom_layout, parent, false);
        }
    }

    final NewsSnippet m = mItems.get(position);
    ImageView m_Icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgNewsIcon);
    TextView m_Titletext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNewsTitle);
    TextView m_Description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
    Button m_ActionButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.actionBtn);
    if (type == 0) {
        RatingBar m_RatingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pop_ratingbar);

        String s = String.valueOf((float) m.s_szrating);
        if (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            m_RatingBar.setRating((float) m.s_szrating);
        }
    }

    m_Titletext.setText(m.s_sztitle);
    m_Description.setText(m.s_szdescription);
    m_ActionButton.setText(m.s_szcta);

    m_ActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(m.s_szlandingUrl));
            v.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
    try {
        String url = m.s_szicon;
        if (url != null && !url.equals(m_Icon.getTag())) {
            m_Icon.setTag(url);

            new CDownloadImageTask(m_Icon)
                    .execute(m.s_szicon);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return v;
}
```

Comment: At which position you want to change layout return that position from getItemViewType when it comes.. you can check it with if condition

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to manage the view you want by some id,if you want alternate view i.e First one then other.
This will help

```
  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(postion%2==0){
            return 2;
         }
        return 1;
    }
```

Now when you inflate the view.ie you have done

```
int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (v == null) {
        // Inflate the layout according to the view type
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (type == 0) {
            // Inflate the layout with image
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_for_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vcom_layout, parent, false);
        }
    }
```

Change if condition if(type==2) else other view.

**And if you manage by some or string the change the condition in getItemType() method according**

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different views then basically you have two different view types.

So, define two view types in the adapter.

```
private static final VIEW_TYPE_FIRST = 0;
private static final VIEW_TYPE_SECOND = 1;
```

So this is how you can identify both the view types.

Now you can use the getItemViewType() to tell the adapter which view should get inflated for which position.

Suppose if you want to show the first view for the first item only and all other as the second item.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
if(position == 0){
   return VIEW_TYPE_FIRST;
}
   return VIEW_TYPE_SECOND;
}
```

So the adapter will inflate the first view type only for the first position and the second view type for all other ones.

Comment: Is your problem solved with this answer? Then please consider accepting and upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change layout on position 0 than do like this

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

         if(position==0)
         return 0;
         else
         return 1;
    }



       @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);// **this return 0 if position is 0 else return 1**

            if (v == null) {
                // Inflate the layout according to the view type
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (type == 0) {
                    // Inflate the layout with image
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_for_layout, parent, false);
                } else {
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vcom_layout, parent, false);
                }
            }

            //other code

       }
```